# How to repeat a textbox(Header) on each page when a row is growing ? - Tablix inside Tablix

Tags: .net, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have one tablix with two rows. One row is containing one tablix and the other one is having another tablix(Tablix inside tablix). Grouped the two rows with one column(Column Name is R_Id).

I done it using this [link](http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2012/03/ssrs-how-to-show-tablix-inside-tablix.html). It was really helpful for the beginners like me.

Here the issue is, I have one textbox with one expression in page header, the value of this expression is retrieving from the second tablix (i.e.second row from the main tablix). So, when first tablix is displaying(i.e. first row from the main tablix), I'm getting #error on that textbox in output screen.

Consider, I have 50 rows in first tablix, and 20 rows in second tablix. After execution, I got 3 pages. In first page, that textbox in header is showing as #error. The same when it comes to third page(here the place, second tablix is starting), I'm able to see the result.

I can guess that the value is not there in first tablix(first row of main tablix), So error occurred. How to give a relation to first row from second row?. Whether I need to add the respective column in first tablix also ?. Or Is any property from tablix/group will make trick? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just use two tables?

Comment: I need to loop 'n' number of ID's in the report. So If i use two tables, then I can't show it as expected.

Comment: You can nest the two tables inside a rectangle (or list) object.

Comment: Is it possible to group the rectangle or list ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the rectangle inside a table yes.

So you can start with a table with a single row and column. Replace the textbox in that only cell with a rectangle. And define a row group for this outer table.

Then place your two tables inside the rectangle as you want it to look. You can even place textboxes above, below or between the tables.

For each group this will generate the two tables and repeat anything inside the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please let me know the following flow is correct. (1). Need to add table,(2). Need to replace the rectangle in a single cell of that table.(3). Later, Need to place my 2 tablix into that rectangle.

Comment: Don't forget to group the fist/outer tablix. But the order is correct.

Comment: Okay. I will try and let you know. Thanks once again

Comment: I tried as you said. But still the header part is showing #error. I did like following, I placed one table with only one row and column. Then I placed one rectangle into it. I grouped the table(single row) with ID. Later I placed my two tablix into that grouped row(i.e. within rectangle).

Comment: What are the expressions you used in your table header? And are you using, 1 or 2 datasets? (Or 3?) Can you maybe edit your question with a visual representation?

Comment: I'm using only one dataset. Expression is similar to like following, Pre_ID : &ReportItems!Pre_Id.value

Comment: That seems wrong, you are grouping on Pre_Id? Then i belive it should be something more like this: `=First(Fields!Pre_id.Value)`

Comment: I'm getting this error in header. And we can't use fields in Report Page header. So I placed the Fields!Pre_Id.Value in one of the textbox which is in report body. Then I called the textbox in header part using ReportItems!textbox.value

Comment: Don't place it in the page header, place it in the table header row... If you want an actual page header then you can even add a header in the outer tablix and add a rectangle in there too. Then you can use this header row as the page row and you'll be able to use Field values.